# Allocating memory on the caller's stack

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, calling-convention

I am writing in C++ using MSVC++ 2012 and my code is targeted for an x86 platform.   I have a situation where it would be advantageous to write a function that (amongst other things) can allocate some memory on the stack of the CALLING function.   Its not my intent in this post to debate the wisdom of doing this, but only to consider the technical feasibility.

My implementation plan is to write my function as a naked function with custom prolog code in inline assembly.  In the prolog I would first determine how much memory I need and then move the return address, parameters, and this pointer down the stack by that amount. Finally I would then adjust the stack pointer by that amount.  If I am not mistaken this would create an area on the stack of the calling function.

Does anyone see any holes in that plan?

Comment: Not really, no, assuming you don't screw up the assembler and there is enough stack space:)  I assume that the stack would need fixing up at some point after the return to remove the allocation space?

Comment: Similar to what [`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) does?

Comment: This is probably an XY problem. `alloca` does what you want as @CaptainObvlious noted, but without any background all solutions might just be pointless

Comment: An obvious problem with moving the stack frame is that any pointers handed-off/stored to variables within it would be invalid.

Comment: @Martin - good thought.  If the caller was itself called using cdecl convention, then the cleanup should be incumbent (it will just restore the stack pointer as it received it).   But if the caller is using stdcall or thiscall, the stack might get corrupted.     Depends on how the compiler wrote the caller's epilog.  If the compiler just subtracts from the stack pointer the size of local variables plus passed in parameters, then it would not account for the new space I created.     I dont know exactly how they write the epilog, and perhaps it varies by compiler.

Comment: @doynax - i am not sure i understand your thought.   Since the current function is at the very bottom of the stack, everything higher would not move and would remain valid.  And there shouldnt be anything lower.  Please clarify if I misunderstand.  Thanks

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, I thought you meant that you wanted to modify the parent stack frame. Then I suppose I don't quite see the problem, why not use `alloca` and let the compiler in on the trick?

Comment: @doynax - I think this is a situation where the frame model for stack visualization actually makes it more difficult.   Consider the stack as simply a downward extending array of 32bit values.  I simply want to insert an arbitrary number of blank spaces in between the last entry from the parent and the first entry from the child.     In essence this is reimplimenting alloca to put the memory on the parents stack frame rather than the childs as it normally would.

Comment: @Josh: I see but unless you clue the compiler in on the trick then it won't know that the stack pointer has been displaced on return. For instance passing parameters to subsequent child functions via the base pointer won't work, and frame-pointer optimization would cause true havoc.

Comment: @Josh - if epb/rbp is used to save/restore the stack pointer, then at least the stack pointer will get restored. The issue is if parameters and local variables are addressed as offsets from esp/rsp (problem here) or epb/rpb (should be ok). Microsoft compilers have an option to disable frame pointers, in which case ebp/rbp is not used to save/restore the stack pointer, and in this case, you'd have a problem.

Answer (score 6):

One obvious disadvantage is that inline assembly is not supported for x64, so you would be limiting your portability in the future.

Another obvious disadvantage is that the calling function will be expecting the stack pointer in a certain place relative to their locals, which it no longer is. I believe that the compiler's generated code would not cope with such a situation. A simple example of this dissonance would be that the generated code would not know how much stack space to pop off.

The only way I have observed to do what you want to do is to use a default parameter. You can do e.g.

```
int f(void* p = alloca(55)) {
}
```

Technically since the default parameter is evaluated in the *calling* function, this would allocate memory from the calling function's stack. However as you may observe the core issue here is calculating how much space you need.

Comment: thats pretty clever.   I never thought of that.  It doesnt work in this instance because, as you pointed out, determining the size required is an issue.  But I will have to remember that technique for the future.

Comment: @Josh: The obvious counter-move is to define a macro which effectively passes in the parameter for you.

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of good points made by several posters.  I will summerize here.

The technique I described WILL work but ONLY if the calling function was defined with CDECL calling convention AND the linker switch disabling stack frame pointers is not enabled.  The calling function must be CDECL, not STDCALL or THISCALL because STDCALL and THISCALL would not correctly restore the stack pointer in the calling function's epilog since those conventions subtract from the current ESP rather than restoring the original value.  They would subtract the wrong amount, not accounting for the added space, and the stack would thus be corrupted.  The linker switch disabling stack frame pointer must not be active because if it is the calling function will reference parameters as offsets from ESP rather than EBP and thus the offsets will not be correct.

In addition to the above limitations the concsequences of using this technique would be loss of x64 portability and unpredictable impact to performance optimizations.

In view of the limitations I have elected not to continue with this technique.